# Is building on XCode 2.5, OS X 10.4 possible with a OS X 10.11.3

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode7, osx-elcapitan, osx-tiger

I couldn't find anything in the search so here this goes:
I am looking to build an XCode Mac OS X app, and it is required to be compatible with XCode 2.5, which is for OS X 10.4. I have an OS X 10.11.3 with a XCode 7.3.1.

I tried downloading XCode 2.5 and installing it, but the setup said I needed to have OS X 10.4 to install. When running XCode 7.3.1 on the OS X 10.11.3, I can get the compiler settings to compile and run  with the minimum deploy OS X version as 10.4, but I am not sure how to convert the project to XCode 2.5.

I was thinking about running VMWare or something, but I'm not really sure how to get a 10.4 Mac OS X image. Can someone help me figure out what I can do? Would I have to compile projects manually through an older version of compilers? Thanks guys!

Comment: Is your requirement that it must run on a 10.4 machine, or do you need to upgrade from Xcode 2.5 to Xcode 7/8 and have in running on the latest macOS version?

Comment: Yes, my requirement is that it must run on the 10.4 machine. I don't need to upgrade XCode, as I have 7.3 but need 2.5. It's more like downgrading. Kind of weird. I'm hoping to get some clarification soon.

Comment: Just a note on the VMWare idea: only 10.6 Server (Snow Leopard) and above can be run in a virtual environment. Lower versions won't install - some kind of licensing thing from what I gather.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Xcode 2.5 to build binaries for 10.4. What you need is:

- The Mac OS X 10.4 SDK
- A compatible compiler: GCC 4.0 is recommended, but GCC 4.2 works as well. Things get a bit more complicated if you need C++11 support as well.

A solution is to install the compilers and SDKs you need using the [XcodeLegacy](https://github.com/devernay/xcodelegacy) script. It extracts these from older Xcode distributions.

You should then be able to select the older Mac OS X SDK and compiler in the Xcode version you have installed. Read carefully the [XcodeLegacy](https://github.com/devernay/xcodelegacy) documentation.